Why would the author write "The cat was curled up" instead of "The cat had curled up"?
'The cat was curled up on the couch, sleeping happily'. I found this sentence in a Cambridge dictionary online, and I don't understand why using 'the cat was curled up' instead of ' the cat curled up'. I mean the cat has its own will to curl so I don't think it passive voice but I can not figure any formula relates to help me explain this sentence

The act of curling up is a transitory event, which wouldn't pair well with simultaneously sleeping happily (an extended activity). But being curled up is an extended activity / state, so it works.

If you like, yeah. But for logical, semantic reasons, not just "syntactic consistency".

Curl up is a phrasal verb. In its in past participle form here, it’s a subject complement and functions like an adjective. Compare The cat was tired.

Maybe call it "semantic parallelism", if you want a label / "formula". But really it's just a matter of logic - if you're gonna pair up up two descriptive verbs about the same subject, it's only logical that they should be "temporally consistent".

You could compare "curled (up)" with "bent" which is more obviously an adjective, or "tucked", "hid/hidden", "folded", "bent over", "folded up", "hidden away", etc, which are often used similarly. The only relevant question I can find is about "I am/was sat" which was generally agreed to be dialectal, so doesn't really match.

"curled up" refers to the act (that happened in the past) and "was curled up" refers to the state (the bodily posture) the cat had assumed.  action vs state.
In that particular case, the simple past tense and the past participle of the verb curl (up) are the same.  But you can tell that "was curled up" has the past participle because was + simple past is not grammatical:

I was took a shower.  ungrammatical
I was drove my car to the store. ungrammatical
I was smiled at the joke. ungrammatical

was + {past participle}  expresses state.

So there is really some kind of formula relate to this sentence and thanks TimR for your information. And do you have any kind of document or anything relates to this knowledege for me to read ?  I will be very happy to read it

Aren't the past participles of take and drive, "taken" and "driven"?

Yes , they are Mari-Lou A

@EvanNguyen.  Not sure why you're asking about past participles when I wrote "... was + simple past is not grammatical: ..."  and followed up with several examples where "was" with a simple past are flagged as "ungrammatical".

Oh sorry , I was too excited when I thought there really are formula for this sentence. But I will go along with 'be curled up' is a phrasal verb

The sentence The cat curled up implies that the observer had seen the cat curling up, the action of curling up. He did not see the cat curl up but only saw that the cat was curled up after the cat, by it's own volition had made itself comfortable by curling up, as cats are wont to do.

OP's query:

Why would the author write "The cat was curled up" instead of "The cat had curled up"?

In  "The cat was curled up on the couch, sleeping happily," "was curled up" uses the past participle  "curled as an adjective.
This describes the cat's state (being curled up) rather than the action of curling up. So, the focus is on how the cat is at that moment—curled up and sleeping—rather than on what the cat did.
Participles can act as adjectives and are used to describe or modify nouns and pronouns.
Often, they indicate something associated with a particular action (e.g., "cooking class," "boxing gloves") or a specific state (e.g., "excited," "depressed").
In regular verbs with -ed endings, it can sometimes be confusing whether the form acts as an adjective or as a verb in the past.
How to differentiate them:.


The presence of a by-agent phrase (by your behaviour, by my reaction) indicates that the -ed form is verbal.
Conversely, the presence of a complement, such as a that-clause, indicates that it is adjectival.

.
Compare the following two constructions:
Adjectival: The jury was convinced that the defendant was innocent.
Verbal: The jury was convinced by the lawyer's argument
.
Here are some further examples of adjectival constructions (with complements) and verbal constructions (with by-agent phrases):

.
If the -ed form is verbal, we can change the passive construction in which it occurs into an active one:



For more examples and details, see the section on adjectival and verbal participles here.
adjectival and verbal constructions.
